# ASP.NET Bundling and minification include dynamic files from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multi-tenant, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing a multi-tenancy MVC 4 application on which the user has some theming possibilities.
He can override every single resource (css, js, jpg, png, ect...) by adding a relative path to a theming table e.g. **/Scripts/booking.js**

Which tenant to use is figured out by the URL e.g. **http://myapp/tenant/Booking/New** this is simply the name of the connection string which should be used.

Therefore if a request is made for a specific resource I first need to check if there is an overridden version of this resource in the database and use it if found.

Now I'd like to implement the new bundling and minification features which microsoft provides in the System.Web.Optimization namespace. But I couldn't figure out how to achieve this with the files in the database.

I've prototyped my own JsMinify implementation to achieve this

```
public class MyJsMinify : JsMinify
{
    private static byte[] GetContentFile(FileInfo filePath)
    {
        string fullName = filePath.FullName;
        int indexOf = fullName.IndexOf("content", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        string substring = fullName.Substring(indexOf + 8).Replace(@"\\", "/").Replace(@"\", "/");

        ThemingService themingService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ThemingService>();
        Theming myTheming = themingService.Find(new ThemingFilter { FilePathLike = substring });
        if (myTheming == null)
        {
            return themingService.GetContentFile(fullName);
        }
        return myTheming.FileData;
    }

    public override void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in response.Files)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(GetContentFile(fileInfo)))
            {
                using (StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, true))
                {
                    newContent.AppendLine(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }

        response.Content = newContent.ToString();

        base.Process(context, response);
    }
}
```

This seems to work if I'm in Release mode but while developing I'd like to get each single script referenced independently. This is automatically done throughout the bundling and minification framework. The Resource URL's generated by the framework looks like the following

```
<script src="/myapp/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

but should look like this

```
<script src="/myapp/tenant/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

I've configured the following Routes:

```
routeCollection.MapRoute("Content1", "{mandator}/Content/{*filePath}", new { mandator = defaultMandator, controller = "Environment", action = "ContentFile" }, new { mandator = mandatorConstraints });
routeCollection.MapRoute("Content2", "Content/{*filePath}", new { mandator = defaultMandator, controller = "Environment", action = "ContentFile" }, new { mandator = mandatorConstraints });
```

The ContentFile Method looks like this

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [AcceptType(HttpTypes.All)]
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ContentFile")]
    public ActionResult ContentFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.Compare(filePath, "Stylesheets/Import.css", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return GetContentImport(CssFileArray, "Stylesheets/");
        }
        if (string.Compare(filePath, "Stylesheets/ImportOutlook.css", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return GetContentImport(OutlookCssFileArray, "Stylesheets/");
        }
        if (string.Compare(filePath, "Scripts/OutlookAddin/Import.js", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return GetContentImport(OutlookJsFileArray, "Scripts/");
        }
        return new FileContentResult(GetContentFile(filePath), MimeType(filePath));
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea how I could achieve this?
Is there a multi-tenancy pattern to follow?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure I completely understand your scenario, but I believe this is what VirtualPathProviders could be used for.

We added support in the 1.1-alpha1 release, so bundles will automatically use the VirtualPathProvider registered with ASP.NET to fetch the contents of the file.

If you were to write a custom VPP that is able to always return the correct version of ~/Scripts/booking.js, everything should just work.